# How to add flatten input to keras object model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using *concatenate* to update the code which used *merge* previously.
However i do not know how to add Flatten() to the input_shape in the keras object model.

**Previous version**

```
def linear_model_combined(optimizer='Adadelta'):
    
    modela = Sequential()
    modela.add(Flatten(input_shape=(100, 34)))
    modela.add(Dense(1024))
    modela.add(Activation('relu'))
    modela.add(Dense(512))
    
    modelb = Sequential()
    modelb.add(Flatten(input_shape=(100, 34)))
    modelb.add(Dense(1024))
    modelb.add(Activation('relu'))
    modelb.add(Dense(512))
    
    model_combined = Sequential()
    model_combined.add(merge([modela, modelb], mode='concat'))
    model_combined = concatenate([modela,modelb])
    model_combined.add(Activation('relu'))
    model_combined.add(Dense(256))
    model_combined.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model_combined.add(Dense(4))
    model_combined.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model_combined.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model_combined
```

**What i am trying to make it work:**

```
def linear_model_combined(optimizer='Adadelta'):
    
    modela_in = Input(shape=(100,34))
    modela_out1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='layer_a1')(modela_in)
    modela_out2 = Dense(512,activation='relu',name='layer_a2')(modela_out1)
    modela = Model(modela_in,modela_out2)
    
    modelb_in = Input(shape=(100,34))
    modelb_out1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='layer_b1')(modelb_in)
    modelb_out2 = Dense(512,activation='relu',name='layer_b2')(modelb_out1)
    modelb = Model(modelb_in,modelb_out2)
    
    modelconcat_in = concatenate([modela_out2,modelb_out2])
    modelconcat_out1 = Dense(256,activation='relu',name='layer_c1')(modelconcat_in)
    modelconcat_out = Dense(4,activation='softmax',name='layer_c2')(modelconcat_out1)
    
    model_merged = Model([modela_in,modelb_in], modelconcat_out)
    model_merged.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
   
    return model_merged
```

**Model training:**

```
model = linear_model_combined()
hist = model.fit([x_train_speech, x_train_speech2], Y, 
                 batch_size=100, epochs =80, verbose=1, shuffle = True, 
                 validation_split=0.2)
```

I do not know how to match the shapes exactly. I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 100, 4) are incompatible
```

Comment: it seems that you need to operate a flattening in linear_model_combined because I suppose your target is 2D while your model is producing 3D

Comment: Yes, but i could not figure out, how to add flattening to this.

Comment: u simply need to add a Flatten layer between modelX_in and modelX_out1

Comment: AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'add'. I get this error when i add a layer.

Comment: pay attention, u are using a functional format of keras: it's modelX_flt = Flatten()(modelX_in).... and the following layer is Dense(.... ,name='layer_X1')(modelX_flt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it worked when i tried to add Flatten() as suggested in the comments.
I realized i was trying to use Flatten() in a sequential model coding way for object model.
So, Flatten() must be used before passing the object model as in code and it works!

Thankyou!

```
def linear_model_combined(optimizer='Adadelta'):
    
    modela_in = Input(shape=(100,34))
    modela_inf = Flatten()(modela_in)
    modela_out1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='layer_a1')(modela_inf)
    modela_out2 = Dense(512,activation='relu',name='layer_a2')(modela_out1)
    modela = Model(modela_in,modela_out2)
    
    modelb_in = Input(shape=(100,34))
    modelb_inf = Flatten()(modelb_in)
    modelb_out1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='layer_b1')(modelb_inf)
    modelb_out2 = Dense(512,activation='relu',name='layer_b2')(modelb_out1)
    modelb = Model(modelb_in,modelb_out2)
    
    modelconcat_in = concatenate([modela_out2,modelb_out2])
    modelconcat_out1 = Dense(256,activation='relu',name='layer_c1')(modelconcat_in)
    modelconcat_out = Dense(4,activation='softmax',name='layer_c2')(modelconcat_out1)
    
    model_merged = Model([modela_in,modelb_in], modelconcat_out)
    model_merged.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model_merged
```